# Java Caching System - finding map size

Tags: java, caching

I'm using Java Caching System (JCS  - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/ ) I need to find the size of a cache (from the class org.apache.commons.jcs.access.CacheAccess)

With CacheAccess.getStats() I can get a String that gives me the stats of a cache

e.g.

```
String stats = ((ICacheAccess<String, Book>) cache).getStats();
```

And will give me lots of info

```
Region Name = bookCache
HitCountRam = 0
HitCountAux = 0
---------------------------Memory Cache
List Size = 5015
Map Size = 5015
Put Count = 5015
Hit Count = 0
Miss Count = 0
---------------------------Indexed Disk Cache
Is Alive = true
Key Map Size = 0
Data File Length = 0
Hit Count = 0
Bytes Free = 0
Optimize Operation Count = 0
Times Optimized = 0
Recycle Count = 0
Recycle Bin Size = 0
Startup Size = 0
Purgatory Hits = 0
Purgatory Size = 0
Working = true
Alive = false
Empty = true
Size = 0
```

but all I need is the Map or List Size.

Any ideas - other than regex :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
List<IStatElement> stats = ((ICacheAccess<String, Book>) cache).getStatistics().getStatsElements();
// using CollectionsUtil from commons-collection
CollectionsUtil.select(stats, new Predicate<IStatElement>() {
    public boolean evaluate(IStatElement elem) {
        String name = elem.getName();
        return "List Size".equals(name) || "Map Size".equals(name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask which commons-collection? I have commons-collections4-4.0.jar, but CollectionUtil is not showing up.

Comment: It is Collection(s)Util, not CollectionUtil. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not as elegant as the one from @DJ. But here goes:

```
    /**
     * Get the AuxiliaryCacheStats from the Statistics for the CacheAccess
     * and from get make a List of the first element
     */
    IStats list = ((ICacheAccess<String, Book>) cache).getStatistics().getAuxiliaryCacheStats().get(0);


    /**
     * Here are the List Size and Map Size
     */
    System.out.println("List Cache : "  + list.getStatElements().get(0));
    System.out.println("List Cache : "  + list.getStatElements().get(1));

    /**
     * Do some substrings
     */
    int listSize = Integer.parseInt(list.getStatElements().get(0).toString().substring(12));
    int mapSize = Integer.parseInt(list.getStatElements().get(1).toString().substring(11));

    System.out.println("From cache list size : " + listSize);
    System.out.println("From cache map size : " + mapSize);
```